# Comparing topologies on $I \times I$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am following the hints given by Brian M. Scott in [Prob. 10 after Sec. 16 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd edition: Which of these topologies is finer than which?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174646/prob-10-after-sec-16-in-munkres-topology-2nd-edition-which-of-these-topolog?rq=1) (refer to the link for the used symbols). Is my reasoning correct?

(i) $(1/2,1] \times [0,1/2) \in \tau$, because it is a cartesian product of open sets of $[0,1]$. If a basis element $A$ of $\tau_d$ is such that it contains the point $(0,1)$, then it must be of the form $$(\{x_1\} \times (y_1,1])\ \cup ((x_1,x_2) \times I) \ \cup (\{x_2\}\times[0,y_2),\text{where} \ x_1 < x_2$$ or $$([0,x) \times I) \ \cup (\{x\} \times [0,y), \text{where} \ 0 < x, y \leq 1$$ or $$(\{x\} \times (y,1]) \ \cup ((x,1] \times I), \text{where} \ 0 \leq x, y < 1$$ Thus $A$ cannot be contained in $(1/2,1] \times [0,1/2)$ so $\tau \nsubseteq \tau_d$.

(ii) $\{1/3\} \times (1/3, 1/2) \in \tau_d$, but if a basis element $B$ of $\tau$ contains the point $(1/3, 5/12)$ and the set $\{1/3\} \times (1/3, 1/2)$, $B$ must contain some neighborhood of $(1/3, 5/12)$, so $B \not \subset \{1/3\} \times (1/3, 1/2) $ and thus $\tau_d \nsubseteq \tau$ so they're incomparable.

(iii) For any basis element A of $\tau_d$, we can express it as a union of sets $\{x\} \times [(a,b) \cap I]$ and thus  $\tau_d \subseteq \tau_s$. (I'm unsure of the details here; do we consider all possible cases, or is there a sufficient argument that doesn't require casework?).

(iv) $\{0\} \times (0,1] = \{0\} \times (I \cap (0,2)) \in \tau_s$. If a basis element A of $\tau_d$ contains the point $(0,1)$, it must also contain the point $(0,0)$. Now $A \not \subset \{0\} \times (0,1]$ so $\tau_d \subsetneq \tau_s$.

(v) Every basis element of $\tau$ is some $[(a,b) \cap I] \times [(c,d) \cap I]$ can be represented as the union of basis sets $\tau_s$, so $\tau \subseteq \tau_s$

I'm not sure (i), (iii) and (v) are correct. I'd be very grateful if someone could point out **any** errors and ways to improve them.